# Paypal notify_url and credit card payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Under my Sandbox account, i can't find an option to generate a fake credit card to test. When i look at the credit card section there's no option to generate one either.

I have a HTML form that calls PayPal and the user can make payments using their PayPal account and have set notify_url to receive the response.

If the user pays with their card, would the notify_url pick up the response too as it would when paying using a PayPal account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Under my Sandbox account, i can't find an option to generate a fake credit card to test. When i look at the credit card section there's no option to generate one either.

You have to create test accounts inside the sandbox account: a business account to receive the payments and IPNs and a user account with a CC to make the test payments.

> I have a HTML form that calls PayPal and the user can make payments using there PayPal account and have set notify_url to receive the response.
>
> If the user pays with their card, would the notify_url pick up the response too as it would when paying using a PayPal account?

Yes. You will get all the relevant information in the IPN transaction.

Comment: Hello EJP, I have a querstion regarding paypal funds can you help me . here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365653/using-master-and-visa-credit-cards-in-paypal-payment . Thanks in advance