# Using Master and Visa credit cards in paypal payment

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal payment Gateway with credit card only. According to Paypal Document, if we create a payment it means (create a new payment and also process the same). In both of the below cases create payment works successfully.

1. On creating payment with Master or Visa credit cards my funds doesnot appear in my sandbox account.
2. But when i use Discover credit card my funds raise on same sandbox account.

I also have gone through execute payment method but in documentations it says execute payment methods works only when payment is from paypal account and not credit card.

And also is it possible that this problem doesnot appear on paypal main account and only happens to be with sandbox account. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me i am stucked here from last few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Paypal doc](https://www.paypal.com/in/selfhelp/article/where-can-i-find-test-credit-card-numbers-ts2157/) for your query.

I tested using their test cards and works well for me. Let me know if still you are facing issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I was also stucked in the same problem. But didn't got any appropriate solution.

What i can say is wait for some time to raise funds from Master and Visa cards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it so, because i am waiting from last few days(6 - 7 days) but nothing came into existance ?